# Error en código de java "java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError"

Tags: java

tengo que hacer un programa que introducido Lunes, Febrero, 2019, te transforme esos datos a, por ejemplo, 05/02/2019. Donde el 05 tiene que corresponder al primer lunes del mes de febrero del 2019.

Por ahora estoy intentando hacer una clase que contenga los datos de los enums DayOfWeek y Month en el idioma por defecto del ordenador cliente, en este caso, español.

Luego, quiero hacer otra clase, que invoque una instancia única de la otra para validar que el día que me han introducido, corresponde a uno de los días que hay en el idioma de origen, como estoy hablando de español, debería introducir lunes y este debería devolver que funciona.

Os muestro los dos códigos:

```java
    package exercise8;

    import java.time.DayOfWeek;
    import java.time.Month;
    import java.time.format.TextStyle;
    import java.util.Locale;

    public class SpanishsInfo {

        /* Atributos */

        /* Array que almacena los meses en español.*/
        private String[] months;

        /* Array que almacena los días en español.*/
        private String[] days;


        /* Constructor */
        public SpanishsInfo() {
            setArrays();
        }

        /* Getters */
        public String[] getMonths() {
            return months;
        }

        public String[] getDays() {
            return days;
        }

        /* Inicializador de array para meses */
        private void setArrays() {

            byte i = 0;

            /* Obtenemos la palabra para el idioma en el que se ejecuta el programa. */
            Locale l = new Locale(Locale.getDefault().toLanguageTag());

            /* Recorre el enum de los meses y los agrega al array month*/
            for(Month m : Month.values()) {
                months[i] = m.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, l);
                i++;
            }

            i = 0;

            /* Recorre el enum de los días y los agrega al array days*/
            for(DayOfWeek d : DayOfWeek.values()) {
                days[i] = d.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, l);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

```java
    package exercise8;

    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import exercise8.ConsoleInput;

    public class CheckWord {

        /* Atributos */

        /* Instancia un objeto de SpanishInfo para obtener los días y meses correctos. */
        private static SpanishsInfo info = new SpanishsInfo();

        /* Instancias para pedir por teclado. */
        private static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        private static ConsoleInput kb = new ConsoleInput(keyboard);

        /* Atributo global para devolver los días y meses. */
        private static String result = null;

        /* Constructor */
        private CheckWord() {};


        /* Inicio */
        public static String getDay() {

            do {
                System.out.println("Introduzca un día de la semana: ");

                /* Pide un día por teclado */
                result = kb.readString().toLowerCase();

                /* Comprueba que la palabra introducida esté dentro
                 * del array pasado. En caso contrario, vuelve a pedir el día. */
            } while (Arrays.binarySearch(info.getDays(), result) > 0);

            /* Si el día se encuentra dentro del array, se devuelve la palabra. */
            return result;
        }

    }
```

Tengo una clase App con un main, en la que en lo único que hago es

```
String day = getDay();
```

A priori está todo importado. Cuando inicio el programa, me sale el siguiente problema:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at exercise8.App.main(App.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at exercise8.SpanishsInfo.setArrays(SpanishsInfo.java:43)
    at exercise8.SpanishsInfo.<init>(SpanishsInfo.java:21)
    at exercise8.CheckWord.<clinit>(CheckWord.java:12)
    ... 1 more
```

Estoy intentando que todo sea estático, porque me parece que es la mejor manera de hacerlo.

¿Alguien me puede decir que estoy haciendo mal?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error te está dando en esta línea:

```
months[i] = m.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, l);
```

porque el array `months` no está inicializado en ningún momento. Así que `months` vale null, y te lanza una excepción porque no se puede acceder a una posición de un array nulo.

Tendrás que hacer algo así en algún momento:

```
months = new String[MAX_MONTHS];
```

(donde MAX_MONTHS sería el tamaño máximo del array, supongo que será 12).

Más info:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html